# Android/OpenGles drawing 2 external texture each taking half of the screen. Left and right half

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, surface, egl

I have successfully bind 2 external OES texture to my shader. Now I want each texture to take 1/2 of the screen(Left for one texture right for another). How do I go about doing it? Example:
http://vicceskep.hu/kepek/vicces_funny_007445.jpg 
random image from google

Showing a full picture of each picture. It will be nice to have an efficient method to do it. The code that I am currently referencing from is the bikflake/ grafika code from github.
Visit http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt
To check the code out.

Okay I think i will really give in depth clarification for my question as I do not have much knowledge about 3d projections in open GL. Sorry for the numerous edits on the question.
This is my Vertex Shader code currently

```
    private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =

        // UMVPMATRIX IS AN IDENTITY MATRIX
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        //These are surfacetexture.getTransformationMatrix
        "uniform mat4 uSTMatrixOne;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 uSTMatrixTwo;\n" +        

        "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +

        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoordTwo;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_Position =  uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "    vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
        "    vTextureCoordTwo = (uSTMatrixTwo* aTextureCoord).xy ;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

This is my Fragment Shader code currently which does a overlay currently.

```
        private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoordTwo;\n" +
        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTextureOne;\n" +
        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTextureTwo;\n" +

        "void main() {\n" +
        "    lowp vec4 pixelTop = texture2D(sTextureOne, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "    lowp vec4 pixelBot  = texture2D(sTextureTwo, vTextureCoordTwo);" +

                "    gl_FragColor = pixelTop + pixelBot;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

As for the aPosition and the a texture coordinate it is currently referenced from. It would be nice if someone explained how mTraingleVerticesData works too.

```
    private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {

        // X, Y, Z, U, V
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
};
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
```

My 2 external projection binding currently

```
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

    //Cam Code
    //Set texture to be active
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTwoTextureID);
```

Comment: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt
this is what i am referencing from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea I finally got it.I used 2 different programs to draw and used mTriangleVerticesData to edit the image proportions and use gl_position to shift the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way @Sung suggested but conditional statements and loops in shaders, especialy fragment, are slow. It's better to render 2 different polygons.

Comment: So it is more efficient to draw in 2 separate programs?

Comment: Yes, definitely more efficient.

Comment: I dont want to dive deep into openGL as i am only doing scaling and transformations. I am drawing this to output to an external EGL texture is it still possible to draw twice? It will be nice if you can give me some psuedo code on how it will work as I am really quite lost on this.